# Is it possible to use open graph image rom another host?

Tags: html, facebook-opengraph

I've been searching high and low for an answer for my question. With no luck.

If I run a website on https://www.x.com, can my og:image be from https://www.y.com?

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.y.com/images/thumb.jpg" />
```

Comment: Keep in mind that OG image tags are cached.  So if you changed it and it's not displaying what you intended, you need to use FB dev tools to empty the cache.

Comment: Regrettably, yes. One can create a bunch of pages with opengraph images from whichever site he likes, upload them to some free hosting website, share them on FB, and - voilà! - an FB server will fetch them with no referrer, giving its modest assistance to a DDoS attack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**, all `og` meta tags can showcase a different domain, **even the `url`**, as was purportedly [**discovered by Barak Tawily last month**](https://baraktawily.blogspot.co.il/2017/10/can-you-trust-facebook-links.html). The `og` meta tags are meant to indicate what content is available on a website, though there is no way to know what is *actually* there until a user clicks on the links. Note that while this can be used legitimately, it can also be used to for nefarious purposes.

According to **[TheHackerNews](https://thehackernews.com/2017/10/facebook-link-spoofing.html)**:

> Interestingly, Tawily found that Facebook does not validate if the link mentioned in 'og:url' meta tag is same as the page URL, allowing spammers to spread malicious web pages on Facebook with spoofed URLs by just adding legitimate URLs in 'og:url' Open Graph meta tag on their websites.

**[Tawily's video](https://youtu.be/qWMXBW9k130)** showcases spoofing `og:image` at the same time as spoofing other `og` tags:

[image: Spoof]

All you need to do is set the `content` attribute to the secondary domain.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I found that Facebook will not support cross-domain og:url before you validate it, I got a notifaction when I use Facebook's Sharing Debugger today: "The given value '...' for property 'og:url' will no longer be allowed beginning December 1, 2019, as it belongs to a different domain. To prevent this from affecting your URLs, whitelist the trusted domains using the Webmaster tool." But I can't find any changelog about this.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can be.

An example from the documentation from fb:

```
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
<title>The Rock (1996)</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video.movie" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />
...
</head>
...
</html>
```

The content can be whatever you want it to be.

Reference: http://ogp.me/